Long term monitoring data statistics help
I am still learning statistics and I have some long term monitoring data taken from soil samples in two different forests over 5 months. Soil chemical parameters such as pH and redox, carbon and methane.
I have months, two forest types and two depths ( 10 cm and 50 cm). I want to analyse the differences across months, forest types and depths but I have no idea where to start with the analysis. Can anyone offer any advice?
Best wishes

You might find it very productive to learn some techniques and principles of Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA).

My first rule of statistics is to always First, look at the data!. What Joe Berkson (Mayo Clinic statistician) called the IOTT: Inter Ocular Traumatic Test: "you know what the data mean when the conclusion hits you between the eyes". So plot the data in as many different ways as you can think of (dozens), so you can look at what it says (and equally importantly, what it does not say: I have a hunch that e.g. not all your chemical characteristics change over such a short span as 5 months (some will, others not so much)). And often, plotting it a certain way may give you ideas for a new way to look at the data. Plot it in 1, 2 and 3 dimensions. That will give you hints about what is worth exploring further, and what may not be.
As far as further explorations, I would probably start with factorial ANOVA, aka DOE (Design of Experiment). One DOE analysis for each chemical characteristic you measured. This will give you a regression of your chemical characteristic as a function of your factors (month, forest, depth). More importantly, it will tell you which factor is not significant (i.e. does not seem to affect the chemical measurement), and which interaction (terms which are products of various factors) is not significant. You can then eliminate these factors from the analysis, simplify the model, and repeat the factorial DOE. E.g. if for a given chemical measurement the month is not significant, I would remove it from the DOE, but keep all the measurements and treat them as 5 replicate measurements. While there are many other ways you could analyze the data set (regression, multivariate multiple regression, etc.) I would start with factorial ANOVA to weed out factors and interactions (basically reduce the dimensionality of the problem, thus simplifying further explorations).

I would use a 5x2x2 factorial design. Whether you use multiple regression or anova.
In either case, the model would likely be $ Υ_1 = β_0 + β_1X_{time}+ \beta_2X_{forest}+ β_3X_{depth} + β_4X_{time*forest} + β_5X_{time*depth} + β_6X_{depth*forest} + β_6X_{time*forest*depth} + ε_0 $
The first three predictors are your factors on their own. The next four are the product of the factors listed in the subscript and they represent the interaction effect between the respective variables. This is known as a full-factorial mixed effects model (full factorial because it includes all possible interaction effects, mixed effects because the fixed effects are your factors while the repeated measures introduces random effects.
It’s important to remember that your main effects and interaction effects do not need to all be significant. It’s likely that one of either effect type’s variables won’t be.
As for how to actually do this, that depends on what stats package you’re using and  guides are readily available.
Also, you can also do partial factorial analysis using only some of the factors and levels. This is done if there’s too much data to measure each factor at each level.
One more thing, don’t forget to have multiple samples in each factor group. E.g. if you have 20 groups with 10 samples per group, you will have 200 observations that allow you to assess overall effects as well as within group variability. Google how to calculate the needed sample size per group as well as power analysis.
P.s.,anova and regression are mathematically identical. It doesn’t matter which one you use so long as your model is correct. Though their outputs are slightly different (but can be converted between the two using math). Use which ever method’s output data better suits your needs.
Feel free to reach out again after googling how to do this if you have more questions.
